# How do I apply my texture to fur/hair?

Tags: texturing, hair

I'm working on a model of a cat, I've made the textures and I've applied fur.
I just have no idea how to apply the texture to the fur.

So how do I do that?

Comment: Blender internal or cycles? Maybe [this tutorial](https://www.blenderguru.com/tutorials/fluffy-fur-ball) covers what you want.